# problems with animating image texture on action editor

Tags: animation, image

I tried to do the answer from my previous question, but I couldn't see the keyframes on the action editor. Another thing is that I can't make a second animation for it. like I can only do blinking or only "xx" eyes. Finally, When I do try animating it sometimes it would go through all the other images before it reaches the one, I assign it to.

Comment: hello maybe show some screenshots or share your file?

Comment: For your last sentence, if you mean the Timeline editor and you're using a sequence of images in an Image Texture node, you need to select all the keyframes in the image texture animation, press 'T' and select 'Constant' from the menu which pops up. This will prevent the image sequence cycling between keyframes. As @moonboots says we'll need to see some images and/or your Blend file (with your image packed into) it to be sure.

Comment: ok but what about how I'm unable to see the image sequence's keyframes on the action editor

Comment: As moonboots and I said, we'll need to see your Blend file and some screenshots.  You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it. You'll need to pack the images into it first though via File > External Data > Pack Resources in Blender.